# Gitosis publickey permission denied

Tags: git, ssh, github, redmine, gitosis

I have a gitosis server at work, and I also use github for personal projects, Im trying to use the same public and private ssh keys for both accounts, the only difference would be the username which in gitosis is md.mercado49 and in github is maumercado.

I already uploaded my public key on to gitosis and of course Ive had it for some time on github, now the problem is I have permission denied when trying to connect to the gitosis server, but its successful when connecting to github with the same key.

Heres what I get with the ssh -vT gitosis@repocomit.virtual.uniandes.edu.co command:

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to repocomit.virtual.uniandes.edu.co [157.253.238.144] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'repocomit.virtual.uniandes.edu.co' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/maumercado/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Is it even possible to do what Im trying to do, authenticate with the same key and different usernames and emails?

Should I generate a different key for the other account, if so, how?

Thanks all for your help!

... Also and I believe irrelevant but who knows, I set up git global config with the github information but on the project for the company I have git config --local... that should be no problem right?

==== UPDATE ====

So I've noticed that in the debug section the following:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Why is it giving id_rsa as my public key when its actually the private key and id_dsa as my private key when that does not even exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a looong debugging time, thinking and analyzing, I redid everything following this http://dev.remarkablewit.com/redmine/projects/dev-server/wiki, it works, at least for me, also in the gitosis.conf I added under [gitosis] loglevel=DEBUG to help me out a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction on how often you use a public ssh key and where. The name in the key is more for documental purposes. As long as the system supports the type of key (RSA/DSA).

Did gitosis ever work with your key? It's a bit tricky in configuration. Also ensure that there are no line breaks in it's key file there.

Regarding your git config question: Local settings override global ones. But thats just fine the way you do it.

Comment: Hello @iltempo, actually is still giving the same problem, the gitosis server key is a dsa. I've checked my key in the redmine-gitosis plugin Public Keys, and theres nothing weird in there, like a space or anything!

Comment: I don't know what redmine is doing to gitosis. May you post you configuration?

Comment: Which file would you like me to give you... or you are talking about the plugin configuration in redmine, if so here it is -> http://cl.ly/072e14363L0G2R1g2v46

Comment: Do you need any more configuration files?? or maybe something to test further?

Comment: Had a look on the screenshot. Where do you set up that your ssh key `/Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_dsa` is allowed to access repos on the gitosis server?

Comment: Can't find anything. The SSH trace you provided is not unusual. Looks the same here. SSH is trying the two common names for keys. The wording is misleading. The /Users/maumercado/.ssh/id_rsa simply doesn't match. Do you have a chance to look into .ssh/authorized_keys for gitosis@repocomit.virtual.uniandes.edu.co?

Comment: Sure what do you need from there?

Comment: wel the ssh authorized_keys is in there... with the gitosis public key... the authorized keys is in /srv/gitosis/.ssh/

Comment: Still having the same issue... :S

Comment: dont.. worry, thank you for trying to help out... Ive being out of ideas for 3 days now :S

Comment: Ummm I did a little change on the ssh settings on the server, now the repository is asking for a gitosis password in order to push or connect to the server, also, when I enter the gitosis password now it states fatal: 'myrepo.git' does not appear to be a git repository